# What is an acceptable gap for a lower-bound?

Tags: bounds, optimality-gap

Based on your experience, I want to know what is called an *acceptable* lower-bound.

I know it can be different based on the problem. For example, is 5% is an acceptable lower-bound gap for VRPTW? By gap, I mean (LB-OP)/OP * 100, where OP is the optimal value.

Please share your thoughts with regard to the problem.

Comment: Acceptability is in the mind of the acceptor.

Comment: 3.141592653589793%

Comment: It can be useful for the reader to have an explanation or at least a link to an explanation of VRPTW.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I endorse Mark L. Stone's comment (which should be the answer).

That said, what is considered an acceptable gap is likely to depend not only on the nature (and perhaps dimension) of the *problem* being solved but also on the nature of the *model* being used. If a model is known to have weak bounds, the user probably should be willing to accept a larger terminal gap. (Note that I said *should* be.) If the model is known to have tight bounds, it would be more reasonable to hold out for a smaller terminal gap.

Comment: Thanks for the response.